# Migrating Wordpress blog to New Webhosts, something is adding a # and gibberish

Tags: permalinks, migration

I just migrated a WordPress blog from one host provider to another.

Did a clean install on the new server, and everything seems to be working fine except all the permalinks for some reason add a string on the end like this:

http://keefermadness.com/2011/09/behind-the-scenes-of-my-nasa-grail-experience-day-one-am#.Tpq5DpzpP-g

That #.Tpq5DpzpP-g shouldn't be there. Any idea where this is coming from and how to eliminate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I just figured it out. In the migration, the settings were slightly different in the "Add This" plugin. I had selected "Track address bar shares" which added the # and the characters for tracking purposes. That is now removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following.

1. Try to look your permalinks structure
2. search this string in your mysql database
3. Download all your theme files and search it in.
4. Check your htaccess

Above steps may fix it.

Comment: Problem is the string changes per visit. Same page is currently http://keefermadness.com/2011/09/behind-the-scenes-of-my-nasa-grail-experience-day-one-am/#.TpxmF5xZhu1 Is it some sort of session ID?